# I have 2 elements in a div side by side, will hiding one make the other expand to fill the space of the div they're in?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The app has 3 rows of 2 tables each [in the code snippet there's just one row] and I'm trying to create events that:

1. Header is clicked
2. The other table in the row becomes hidden
3. The table with the clicked header expands to fill the div space

Is this possible?

I've tried using Bootstrap expand and collapse but that doesn't really fulfill what I want the code to do.

```
<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-header bg-dark text-white">
                                        Post Change
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body" style="height: calc(100vh - 400px); overflow-y: auto;">
                                        <div class="col-12">
                                            <table class="table table-hover" id="table" data-toggle="table" data-filter-control="true" data-id-field="id" data-height="650" data-pagination="true" data-page-list="[10,25]" data-sort-name="memui" data-sort-order="asc">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        [TABLE GOES HERE]
                                                    </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-6">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-header bg-dark text-white">
                                        New Members
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body" style="height: calc(100vh - 400px); overflow-y: auto;">
                                        <div class="col-12">
                                            <table class="table table-hover" id="table" data-toggle="table" data-filter-control="true" data-id-field="id" data-height="650" data-pagination="true" data-page-list="[10,25,50,100,250,500]" data-sort-name="memui" data-sort-order="asc">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                     [TABLE GOES HERE]
                                                    </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
```

I am expecting the clicked table to expand to fill the space the other hidden table takes up when it becomes hidden.

Comment: Hi @Iwolian, it would be good if you could provide the code using jsfiddle or codepen that way everyone would be able to see the exact functionality and provide suggestion on how it can be fixed. Only HTML code won't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish this, add a click event handler to the header for each table. In these handlers, you can hide the div you don't want to be shown, but you will also need to update the displayed div to make it use the remaining space. This can be done by adding the col-12 class and removing the col-6 class (also during the same event).

I'm not sure if you're using any libraries, but with jQuery it would look something like this:

```
$('#table1headerid').click(function(){
    $('#div2id').hide();
    $('#div1id').removeClass('col-6').addClass('col-12');
});

$('#table2headerid').click(function(){
    $('#div1id').hide();
    $('#div2id').removeClass('col-6').addClass('col-12');
});
```

This can be done without jQuery of course, but I'm lazy :)

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Was able to optimize it a bit so I could implement it easily for the other rows with some funky JQuery functions.

Answer (score 0):

> ****TO VIEW THIS PLEASE CLICK EXPAND SNIPPET ****

In here what I did was just add `JQuery` and toggle the `col-6` with `col-md-11` and `col-md-1`. I didnt hide the `DIV`. If you wants to hide a dive you can use `d-none` in JQuery.

```js
  function hideOrExpandDivPostChange(){
    $('#postChange').toggleClass('col-md-1');
    $('#newMember').toggleClass('col-md-11');
  }
  function hideOrExpandDivNewMember(){
    $('#newMember').toggleClass('col-md-11');
    $('#postChange').toggleClass('col-md-1');
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  
                            <div class="col-6" id="postChange" onclick="hideOrExpandDivPostChange()">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-header bg-dark text-white">
                                        Post Change
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body" style="height: calc(100vh - 400px); overflow-y: auto;">
                                        <div class="col-12">
                                            <table class="table table-hover" id="table" data-toggle="table" data-filter-control="true" data-id-field="id" data-height="650" data-pagination="true" data-page-list="[10,25]" data-sort-name="memui" data-sort-order="asc">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        [TABLE GOES HERE]
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
              
                            <div class="col-6" id="newMember" onclick="hideOrExpandDivNewMember()">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-header bg-dark text-white">
                                        New Members
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body" style="height: calc(100vh - 400px); overflow-y: auto;">
                                        <div class="col-12">
                                            <table class="table table-hover" id="table" data-toggle="table" data-filter-control="true" data-id-field="id" data-height="650" data-pagination="true" data-page-list="[10,25,50,100,250,500]" data-sort-name="memui" data-sort-order="asc">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                     [TABLE GOES HERE]
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```